# presto sql: multiple join with `using` statement

Tags: sql, presto

I have multiple tables and I join them (they share the same key) like this

```
select *
from user_account_profile
inner join user_asset_profile
using (user_id)
left join user_trading_profile
using (user_id)
```

I want to know how will the key `user_id` be used?, is it equivalent to

```
select *
from user_account_profile t1
inner join user_asset_profile t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
left join user_trading_profile t3
on t1.user_id = t3.user_id
```

or

```
select *
from user_account_profile t1
inner join user_asset_profile t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
left join user_trading_profile t3
on t2.user_id = t3.user_id
```

or if these queries are all equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two versions are functionally equivalent (except for the obvious difference of a duplicated `user_id` column when not using `using`).  The first `inner join` mandates that the two `user_id`s have the same value, so either comparison returns the same result set.

If you had a series of `left join`s then you would be requiring that the value be in the *first* table, and the equivalent would be `t1.user_id`.

If you had `full join`s, then you would not know.  The matching would be from the table that has a value on the row.  If both tables have a value, the logic says that they are the same, so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: There is slight difference between `ON a.id = b.id` and `USING (id)`. In the latter case, there is only one `id` column in resulting relation and you don't need to (and cannot) qualify `id` with table/alias.